# max if criteria match + vlookup

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, max

I currently have the following Max If formula.

{=MAX(IF(A1:A5=A13,H1:H5))}

This would work fine, the only problem is that the h1:h5 values are not numeric. I was thinking of doing a mapping (i.e. a vlookup) of the entries to a numeric value but can't seem to fit in the lookup within the function. I know worst case I can create a separate vlookup formula and find the max based on the lookup of those values, but I'd like to avoid that. Please provide any guidance.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Please show create some test data and expected outcome in the original post.

Comment: What is the "max" if the values are not numeric?

Comment: Added a pic which hopefully shows some clarity, basically It's doing a max on the purple values if the blue values match with whatever is in the red cell. I want the purple highlighted values to map to a numeric value and perform a max based on that numeric value. You can see the mapping on rows 18 and 19

Comment: So what would the answer be?

Comment: The answer would be 1. Text2 maps to 1, Text1 maps to 0. Both are matches, and the max of the two would be 1, If that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Use this array formula:

```
=MAX(IF(A1:A5=A13,LOOKUP(H1:H5,A15:A16,B15:B16)))
```

Being and array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]